# Form does not submit

Tags: php, html, forms

Good evening,

I have a form which is supposed to redirect me to cart.php but it is not working. Here is my code:

```
<tr align='center'>

            <td colspan='3'>
                <form method="post" action="cart.php">
                <input type="submit" name="action"  value="View Cart"/>
            <td>
        </tr>
        </form>
    </table>
```

When the button is clicked it remains in the current page. Any help please.. when i put the form at the end which means before the `</body>` it works. i have another form before this code which is this:

```
<form method='post' action='xbox.php'>

                <input type='hidden' name='isPostBack' value='true'/>
                <input type='hidden' name='productid' value='$row[ProductId]'/>
                <tr align='center'>
                    <td>
                        <input type='text' name='qty' class='inputtext'/>
                        <input type='submit' name='action' value='Buy now'/>
                        </form>
```

Is there a way to work the both forms and leave the first form before the second one?

Comment: Your HTML is not valid.  Your `</form>` is after the close `</tr>`.

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript on the page? Also, your HTML isn't valid. Please [validate your HTML](http://validator.w3.org/) first.

Comment: What browsers & version are you using?

Comment: @user1114676: Your HTML is still jacked.  Post your entire html on jsfiddle.net

Comment: I suspect you have a form inside of a table. That normally causes alot of troubles with forms.

Answer (score 11):

Your html is incorrect, it should work when you put the closing form tag after the input:

```
    <td colspan='3'>
        <form method="post" action="cart.php">
            <input type="submit" name="action"  value="View Cart"/>
        </form>
    </td>
```

Your edited html does not validate either, so I would strongly recommend starting with valid html.

Anyway, although you are not showing all html, an additional problem could be that you have nested forms. You can have multiple forms on a page, but after each other, not nested. So this should work just fine:

```
<form method='post' action='xbox.php'>
...
</form>
...
<form method="post" action="cart.php">
    <input type="submit" name="action"  value="View Cart"/>
</form>
```

Comment: @user1114676 I would start with putting the page through an html validator.

Comment: @MrGlass Maybe, but it would not be the first time a form-submit problem would be solved on SO by fixing the html.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML is not well formed. It should be:

```
        <td colspan='3'>
            <form method="post" action="cart.php">
            <input type="submit" name="action"  value="View Cart"/>
            </form>
        <td>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have tags intermingled.  Sometimes it works because the parsers are somewhat forgiving, but it's not proper.  Bring your  tag under your input tag, and before your next  tag (btw, your second td tag isn't closed, either)

Comment: now i closed the td and put the form outside the table but still not working.

Comment: See how you have an opening TR and TD before the closing TABLE?  That's the tag intermingling I'm talking about.  You can't do that.  You can nest tags, i.e. <1><2></2></1>, but not intermingle, i.e. <1><2></1></2>...  Move the </form> tag before the <td>, after the <input />.  Also, close the <td> after the <input /> tag.